# Problem inflating MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'm going through the documentation at [Hello, MapView](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) to add a MapView to my Activity.

When I launch my Activity, I get an inflation error on the MapView.

Here is the MapView in my layout xml:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mymap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="withheld"
    />
```

Here is the code in my MapActivity (the class is named ActivityDetails and extends MapActivity) class:

```
    MapView mMap;
    mMap = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);
    mMap.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Here is the error:

```
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.activity.ActivityDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.my.app.activity.ActivityDetails.onCreate(ActivityDetails.java:128)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     ... 11 more
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:237)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     ... 23 more
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.setupMapView(MapActivity.java:183)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:279)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:254)
06-10 09:15:24.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(228):     ... 27 more
```

As far as I can tell, I've done everything correct as described in the documentation. I've set my build target to Google APIs, I've added the uses-library tag to my Manifest, I'm running in an emulator with the Google API target...

Comment: MapActivity.Java is part of the Google APIs library

Comment: Just removed my stupidity off the internet :-P .. well tried to :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was I was calling super.onCreate() after setContentView() in the MapActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong xml for your MapView

The class extending the MapActivity should call setContentView() with the xml containing stuff like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/racemap"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0px"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="blahblahblah" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So instead of using layout_details.xml use layout.xml

Comment: That is what I have: public class ActivityDetails extends MapActivity

Comment: oh whats on ActivityDetails.java:128 ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.layout_details);

Comment: Ah, I've figured out the problem. super.onCreate() is being called after setContentView().  Normally this doesn't hurt, but MapActivity must have some initializing that is required before setting the content view

Answer (score 0):

Insert this on your xml declaration of the MapView

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```